# Using "--ivs" is a good way for making a smaller output?

Tags: wpa

```
airodump-ng --ivs --channel 1 --write output --bssid VV:II:CC:TT:II:MM mon0
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector

**Question**: If we use "--ivs" to make smaller outputs, will we be still able to crack WPA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will still be able to crack WPA. `-i` or `--ivs` is used to only save IVs, which is only useful for cracking anyway.

Comment: I could accept this if you can link any official documentation, because I cannot find any. :\ Many thanks!

Comment: @LoukiosValentine79: http://linux.die.net/man/1/airodump-ng