# SMP support for cracking WPA passwords

Tags: aircrack-ng

We can use aircrack-ng for cracking .ivs files.

But, are there any softwares that support multi-threading, SMP?

Comment: IV are used in wep authentication IIRC. You can crack WPA-handshakes with Hashcat (recently opensourced) or John The Ripper.

Comment: .ivs can be used for WPA cracking: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231525/using-ivs-is-a-good-way-for-making-a-smaller-output

Comment: please post hashcat as the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the open-source software Hashcat. See its [GitHub
repository](https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat). It's open-source,
runs on Windows and Linux. It supports GPUs (in the [oclHashcat
variant](https://github.com/hashcat/oclHashcat)) and multiple
cores. If you want to play around with it, you can use the Kali Linux
live CD which has Hashcat preinstalled.

Comment: Does Hashcat really support GPUs? Its readme prominently says "CPU-based".

Comment: hashcat quite famously supports GPU use.

Comment: http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/

Comment: I updated your answer to add a link to the version that supports GPUs.